# MAX in SELECT statement

Tags: mysql, database, select, insert

```
username   level
me          1
you         1
me          2
me          3
you         1
```

I want to get the highest value for each username. So it should give me 3 for 'me', and 1 for 'you'. How do I do this in a SELECT statement?

```
INSERT INTO table1 (username, level)
SELECT username, (MAX(level)
WHERE username=username group by username)
FROM table2
```

^ It should be something like that but I can't figure it out.

--EDIT--
This is giving me the same value for the entire level and exp column while they're definitely not all the same:

```
INSERT INTO oitc_test (username, xpboost_expiration, level, exp, kills, games) 
SELECT oitc.username, oitc.xpboost_expiration, MAX(oitc.level), MAX(oitc.exp), oitc_sum.kills, oitc_sum.games 
FROM oitc, oitc_sum 
GROUP by username;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying a complex query; for a simple task.

```
INSERT INTO table1 (username, level) 
SELECT username, MAX(level)
FROM table2
GROUP BY username
```

---

For your second question, you need to use a `JOIN` clause.

```
INSERT INTO oitc_test (username, xpboost_expiration, level, exp, kills, games) 
SELECT o.username, o.xpboost_expiration, MAX(o.level), MAX(o.exp), os.kills, os.games 
FROM oitc o
INNER JOIN oitc_sum os
    ON o.username = os.username
GROUP BY o.username;
```

where I am considering that `username` is the common key in both the tables **`oitc`** and **`oitc_sum`**

Comment: Won't MAX(level) give me the highest value of the entire column? I want the highest value per username.

Comment: its grouped by username, it will give you the max for the column based on the username.

Comment: @ItsHarry What Russel said ^ =)

Comment: @RussellShingleton
I have edited my question, could you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Thank you so much! Finally fixed it =)